# How do I rename a Trello board?

Tags: trello

I have a Trello board set up and I am trying to rename the Board title, but not seeing how this can be done.

Does anyone know how you can rename a Trello board?

Answer (score 7):

The Trello guide is a little bit out of date.  If you are the owner of a board, you can rename it like so:

1. Click the board title (or the "Board Menu" button)
2. Click "Profile"
3. Click the name of the board (at the top)
4. Type in the new name
5. Click Save

Answer (score 6):

> **Editing**
>
> Edit a board title by clicking the title on the board view. Only board admins are able to edit the board title.

From the [Trello guide page](https://trello.com/guide). (Under the **Boards** section.)

[image: Edit Board Title Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to click the "edit" icon next to the board name (the one that looks like a pencil), this brings up a pop-up screen that hovers over your board where you can edit the board title and name.

Simply click on the board title to edit it, you can click the link in the bottom-left corner to edit he board's description.

Answer (score 1):

In the iPad version:

1. Open the board
2. Click the fly-out arrow in the upper right
3. Select 'Board Settings'
4. Change the name